# Why I get html/text content type instead of json?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, google-cloud-storage

When I upload image into Google Cloud Storage I got this

```
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-GUploader-UploadID    AEnB2UrQyfCePM_5kYDFy1sJchgXCTkmRH8sU4S8NrWa-KzVoovFtD5iz8CIAUjegqBfBTK8ACiid0XazBRKqpZRvmUE03JNQg
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars    $0.000000
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage  ms=130 cpu_ms=38
Date    Tue, 05 Apr 2016 14:01:11 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Expires Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Length  0
Server  UploadServer
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Instead of this

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-GUploader-UploadID    AEnB2UqEWk0UEztkHlBDHW5x49RYWkkIfPoHCZ_2g0YpZgvXke7blE7VM8FCJOjoAng6x5kySCLcsoccZVNyS9PdG6UU1F9Q1A
Content-Type    application/json
Content-Encoding    gzip
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars    $0.000041
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage  ms=1256 cpu_ms=359
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Date    Tue, 05 Apr 2016 13:44:20 GMT
Pragma  no-cache
Expires Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control   no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Length  307
Server  UploadServer
```

In my android app, I added header Application/json, and I try to send image as multipart, so the second content type is image/png

Here code from android app:

```
   @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(File... params) {


            File file = params[0];

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest");
            httppost.setHeader("Accept","application/json");

            FileBody filebody = new FileBody(file, ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), file.getName());

            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            multipartEntity.addPart("file", filebody);
            httppost.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());
            System.out.println( "executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine( ) );
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute( httppost );
                Log.i("response", response.getStatusLine().toString());
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            httpclient.getConnectionManager( ).shutdown( );

            return null;
        }
```

Why I get html/text content type instead of json? The server response is 200, but I didn't get any JSON. Please help me. thx

Response:

```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-GUploader-UploadID: AEnB2UqF16tZOCnavA58S1qxTXXopXz5ESh3YIU3ksEv9UsQ6Ro4Oyw03i1CVF7M7GpsLi8_p9ua-agn9upJND_mrXCTGMO-nA
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars: $0.000000
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage: ms=1164 cpu_ms=28
Date: Tue, 05 Apr 2016 14:29:54 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Server: UploadServer
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: I think you should set the Content-Type Header, not the Accept header

Comment: I tried, but there is eror, like this Content type is not ok for this URL. I think this is because I have multipart  ("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")

Comment: What data **are** you getting back from the server? You've only shown the headers, but if you get html back, then maybe you actually are getting some html error page instead of your expected JSON response

Comment: This is my Response updated the question. The response is 200 Ok. But I didn't get any info about image Url,etc. Also it is strange that Content-Length 0 and Dollars 0.000000$. I have a working web solution, and the main diference that here Content-Type text/html;charset=UTF-8

Comment: You are printing `response.getStatusLine()` which only shows the status, not the actual content of the page

Comment: What @cricket_007 said. It would help to actually see what HTML you are getting back. 
Not sure but I think something like this: HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
System.out.println(reader.readLine());

Comment: This is empty: This is after response.getEntity().toString()   org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity@1096cfd6

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was, that I got empty Body, inspite of 200 Ok response.
After a few hours I noticed, that I need to take special `name` in Body

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="news_file"; filename="news.txt"\r\n
```

Before this, I used random name, it was test, abc, etc. BUT. This name is the name of form, so this should be the name of the form, and not what you want. Hope this help somebody.

In android this should looks like this. I use retrofit.

```
  @Multipart
    @POST("/_ah/upload/{key}")
    void imageUpload(@EncodedPath("key") String key, @Part("news_file") TypedFile photoFile,Callback<List<ImageUploadResponse>> callback);
```

Take a look, that `@Part` is the same as name (e.g `news_file`)